# Within a range of cells, how do I enter a formula based on condition with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. I have a range of cells in column B with the format:

1###-2#-3##-4#

[image: Example]

I want to enter a mid formula to get the last cell based on the fact that:

1. the next cell is empty
2. the cell matches the regex pattern

My code doesn't give me any errors but doesn't run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeptProgram()

    Dim regex As String
    Dim Pattern As String
    Dim cell As Range

    regex = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}"

    For Each cell In Range("B1:B600")
        If Pattern = regex And ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "MID(B" & "activecell.Row.Offset(0,-2), 6, 11)"
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

On another note: I used regex in VBA based on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

Comment: What is `Pattern`? Do the hash marks represent numbers - if not, you won't get a match anyway? More fundamentally, you haven't declared or initialized regexp object.

Comment: Should I have done something like `cell.value = regex`? The hash marks do represent numbers.

Comment: `if cell like "####-##-###-##" and cell.offset(1,0) = "" then`

Comment: I suggest you re-read that link which has all the data, e.g. `Dim regEx As New RegExp` early binding. That said, you can use the Like operator in this particular case. (As per Scott's comment.)

Comment: You are missing an `=` in your formula: `...Formula = "MID(B" &...` should be `...Formula = "=MID(B" &...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per all the comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeptProgram()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("B1:B600")
        if cell like "####-##-###-##" and cell.offset(1,0) = "" then
            cell.Offset(2,0).Formula = "=MID(" & cell.Address & ", 6, 11)"
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

After running:

[image]

Comment: It gives me a `type mismatch` error at the if statement. Does "####-##-###-##" make the cell a string?

Comment: It is working for me, do you have errors in the column?

Comment: I have no errors. I'll have to figure this out myself. Now it's giving me a 1004 error, application defined...